# Condicionales en setCellValue phpExcel

Tags: php, php5, phpexcel

como puedo agregar un condicional dentro de ->setCellValue,
por ejemplo:

```
 ->setCellValue('L'. $i, if($suma==4){ $suma=5});
```

---

```
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)

      ->setCellValue('A'. $i, $row['idemp'])
      ->setCellValue('B'. $i, $row['Nombre'])
      ->setCellValue('C'. $i, $row['fecha'])
    ->setCellValue('D'. $i, $row['horas'])
    ->setCellValue('E'. $i, $row['area'])
    ->setCellValue('F'. $i, $detalles['depto'])
      ->setCellValue('G'. $i, $row['turno'])
      ->setCellValue('H'. $i, $datos['fechaEntrada'])
    ->setCellValue('I'. $i, $datos['fechaSalida'])
      ->setCellValue('J'. $i, $datos['sumaHoras'])
      ->setCellValue('K'. $i, $row['horasDia'])
      ->setCellValue('L'. $i, $suma=abs($datos['sumaHoras']-$row['horasDia']))
      ->setCellValue('M'. $i, $suma);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

podría ser de la siguiente forma

```
->setCellValue('L'.$i,(($suma==4)?5:$suma));
```

si $suma=4 entonces imprimir 5 en caso contrario imprimir el valor de $suma